# How to add a jmeter build step to jenkins pipeline when using jmeter maven plugin

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have two stages on jenkins pipeline, and it is expecting to add steps in execute jmeter stage

Could someone help to resolve this....

**I got below error:**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 339: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "Execute Jmeter" @ line 339, column 9.
           stage('Execute Jmeter') {
```

**Below is the code snippet of jenkins pipeline:**

```
pipeline {
  agent {
      label 'qatest'
  }
  tools {
    maven 'Maven'
    jdk 'JDK8'
  }
  environment {
    VIRTUOSO_URL = 'qa.myapp.com'
  }
  stages {
    stage('BUILD') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn clean verify'
      }
    }
    stage('Execute Jmeter') {
        post{
            always{
                dir("scenarioLoadTests/target/jmeter/results/"){
                    sh 'pwd'
                    sh 'mv *myapp_UserLoginAndLogout.csv UserLoginAndLogout.csv '
                      sh 'mv *myapp_myappPortfolioScenario.csv myappPortfolioScenario.csv '
                      sh 'mv *myapp_myappDesign.csv myappDesign.csv '
                      perfReport '*.csv'
                }
            
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `Execute Jmeter` stage has no actual pipeline content to execute inside it. As the error messages states, you need to add some content with `stage`, `parallel`, or `steps` (you probably meant to add `steps`).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use [`script` blocks](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script) like:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'qatest'
    }
    tools {
        maven 'Maven'
        jdk 'JDK8'
    }
    environment {
        VIRTUOSO_URL = 'qa.myapp.com'
    }
    stages {
        stage('BUILD') {
            steps {
                script { // <----------------- here
                    sh 'mvn clean verify'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Execute Jmeter') {
            post {
                always {
                    dir('scenarioLoadTests/target/jmeter/results/') {
                        script { <-------------------------------------- and here
                            sh 'pwd'
                            sh 'mv *myapp_UserLoginAndLogout.csv UserLoginAndLogout.csv '
                            sh 'mv *myapp_myappPortfolioScenario.csv myappPortfolioScenario.csv '
                            sh 'mv *myapp_myappDesign.csv myappDesign.csv '
                            perfReport '*.csv'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More information:

- [Pipeline Maven Integration](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/)
- [Running a JMeter Test via Jenkins Pipeline - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial)

Comment: I have tried with below it's the same 

   stage('Execute Jmeter') {
              when {
              expression { return pipelineStages.contains("JMETER-TEST") }
          }
          post{
           always{
             dir("/target/jmeter/results/"){
               sh 'pwd'
                 perfReport 'jmeter-newtest.csv'
            }
         }
       }     
    }